# AppDomain.Load (Assembly from memory)

Tags: .net, vb.net, .net-assembly, appdomain

I am trying to load an assembly into an AppDomain in memory from a byte array.
Basically, I have a system in which code assemblies are transmitted, and I need to isolate each assembly in its own AppDomain, from which I can initialize an instance.

However, I am struggling to load the assembly itself into the AppDomain; the only way is by having a file, but I am wondering if there is a way to do so without it.

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aHZLq.png)

For me, it would be very convenient to do it by just using the raw assembly bytes.

Thanks in advance ^:)

Comment: Did you figure out the solution ? I have the same problem ... loading assembly from stream to new appdomain :(

Answer (score 1):

According to the [MSDN Documentation for AppDomain.Load()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7hcs6az6(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1) one of the overloads takes a byte array to load an assembly, so I don't really see your problem here.

Here's an example where an assembly has been loaded into `My.Resources` as a byte array:

```
Dim TargetAssembly As Reflection.Assembly = System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.Load(My.Resources.MyAssembly)
```

Comment: I am getting a FileNotFound exception when trying to do exactly that (forgot to mention, sorry).

Comment: @Prionum : You're using `My.Resources` too?

Comment: @Prionum : It works completely fine by me. Please edit your question and include the error message, some code and/or screenshots.

Comment: Viuncent, I forgot to add that I first create a new domain then load the assembly, not the CurrentDomain property.

With CurrentDomain.Load(), it works. However, not when I create a new domain.